# Check if user is in txt list (discordpy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

as you can see below, I'm trying to check whether the `ctx.author` is = to a line in user.txt, I just want to check the txt file if it has the user and executes

```
fusers = open('users.txt', 'r')
users = fusers.readlines()

@user.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == user:
        print("dm from user")
    else:
        print("no dm from user")
```

sorry for my grammer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
users = [] #empty list to store all the users in 'users.txt'

with open('users.txt') as userfile: #opens the users.txt file
    users = userfile.read().split('\n')

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author in users: #if ctx.author is in users list
        print("dm from user")
    else:
        print("no dm from user")
```

This code should achieve what you are trying to do. Comments are included too.

Comment: im getting this error
`
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'event'
`

Comment: @GSStargamer, replace `@user.event` with `@client.event` or `@bot.event`. (`@<botvariable>.event`)